# How do I limit the number of file upload in html?

Tags: html

I want to limit user to select up to 6 files in the input tag. Currently, my input tag is like this:

```
<input type="file" name="question_pic" id="id_question_pic" multiple/>
```

I would like to limit user to select up to 6 files. I can return an error on the server side but I want client side to change it first.

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Pure html = "max-uploads = 1"  or 2 or etc... <input type="file" name="question_pic" id="id_question_pic" accept=".gif, .jpg, .png, .bmp, .GIF, .JPG, .PNG, .BMP" max-uploads = 1>  thought I would throw in file types in case anyone is looking for that too

Answer (score 7):

You can use a jQuery function like this:

```
$('.fileinput').change(function(){
    if(this.files.length>10)
        alert('Too many files')
});
// Prevent submission if limit is exceeded.
$('form').submit(function(){
    if(this.files.length>10)
        return false;
});
```

Comment: You can prevent the upload of more then 10 files in the change-function by clearing the filelists value like so:

`if(this.files.length>10){ alert('to many files'); this.value = ''; }`

Unfortunately you are not allowed to remove items from the filelist object, you only can reset the whole value.

Comment: Thank you for your input Marc. Does it still stand correct in 2020?

Comment: @DrorBar Read about the HTML5 File API here to restrict the count of selected files: http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jquery or Javascript for that like this:

```
<input type="file" name="question_pic" id="id_question_pic" max-uploads = 6/>
```

Then in Jquery You can do this like this

```
Var number_of_uploads;
$("#id_question_pic").change(function() {
    if(number_of_uploads > $(this).attr(max-uploads))
    {
    alert('Your Message');
    }
    else
    {
    number_of_uploads = number_of_uploads + 1;
    }
});
```

You can also do this on your form submission in which you are uploading the file. But if you are using Ajax upload this is fine I think.