# limit number of file in file input html5 (js) and multi field inside same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, file

hello i try to find a good solution to limit number of file in file input
my problem is i need too find a generic solution because html is dynmaic generation and i have multi input in same page (and i want different limit peer field)
html code previwe

```
<input type="file" name="micker[file_upload2][]" accept=".pdf" id="fileupload2" placeholder="Upload field2 mulitple" aria-label="Upload field2 mulitple" class="inputfile required invalid" multiple="" style="margin:0" maxuploads="2" aria-required="true" required="required" aria-invalid="true">
```

i need to add limit function peer field like first 2 and second 10
my idea is to inspire to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15855085/2822359
adding
`max-uploads = 6` to my html and upload.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
           $("body").change(function () {
               var numFiles = $("input",this)[0].files.length;
               var maxuploads = $("input",this)[0].attr(\'data-maxuploads\').toString();
               alert(numFiles);
               if (numFiles > maxuploads ) {
                   alert(\'Your Message\');
                   }else {
                   maxuploads = maxuploads + 1;
                       }
                   });
           });
           });
```

the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

thanks for any help

Comment: `max-uploads` tries to subtract the value of the variable `uploads` from the value of `max`. `'max-uploads'` is something completely different …

Comment: i change max-uploads for maxuploads
now i have this error
```upload.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: maxuploads is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (upload.js:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?ef23cc6c642e3e837ae5b5b80ea7e78e:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js?ef23cc6c642e3e837ae5b5b80ea7e78e:2)```

Comment: `maxuploads` is still the refernce to a variable. You want to pass a _text literal_ (vulgo: “string”) to the function here, that was the point I was trying to make clear to you …

Comment: maybe the code is totaly wrong ... did you have an other proof ?

Comment: Or maybe you just need to learn some of the absolute syntax basics of the language you intend to use here. Are you really not aware of the difference between `foo` and `'foo'` in JavaScript …?

Comment: sorry my english is little limited lol i try to learn ... i kknow difference between foo and 'foo' but i don't understand context ... sorry

Comment: `.attr(foo)` would require that a variable named `foo` exists, and that that variable contains the actual name of the attribute you want to read here. `.attr('bar')` however directly passes the _text_ value `bar` _as_ the name of the attribute to look for.

Comment: hello i update my first post with update my code
=> maxupload attrb is added
=> js code is update
=> error return

Comment: That’s because you are still referring to a _variable_ in that place. This needs to be `$(this).attr('maxuploads')`, with a _string value_ in that place, not a non-existing variable.

Comment: ok no more error ... but limitation doesn't works no message ...
but i am not sure about var number_of_uploads ... nothing is define here ??
how i can find number of file select in input to campare ?

Comment: That variable should probably be properly initialized with `0`, otherwise the script will try to add 1 to `undefined` , which will probably result in `NaN`

Comment: i try to change for
`jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var number_of_uploads;
$("#fileupload2").change(function () {
   if ($("#fileupload2").files.length > $(this).attr(maxuploads)) {
       alert(\'Your Message\');
   }
   else {
       number_of_uploads = number_of_uploads + 1;
   }
});
}); `

Comment: i udpate my initial code to be more clear i hope @CBroe

Comment: Is this actually the first input field in your whole document (in DOM order)? Or are you maybe accessing a field that is not actually of `type="file"` now there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this answers your question: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-to-limit-maximum-items-on-multiple-input-input-type-file-multiple

Here is a little working snippet generated along those lines. I take the maximum allowed numbers of files from the `data-max` attribute of each individual input element.

**Edit:**
I now trigger the file-count-check by the `change` event of each file input (I use "delegated binding", i. e. the listener is attached to the parent `<form>` element). Depending on whether the maximum number is exceeded I disable the submit-button.

```js
const btn=document.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('change',function(ev){
 if(ev.target.type=='file'){
  // I collect the inps here to allow for dynamic pages (varying number of inputs):
  const inps=[...document.querySelectorAll('input[type=file]')];
  btn.disabled=inps.some(inp=>{ // check whether the condition has been violated at least once
    if (inp.files.length>inp.dataset.max){ // show warning for first violation
      console.log(`You are only allowed to upload a maximum of ${inp.dataset.max} files for ${inp.name}!`);
      return true;
    }
  })
 }
});
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title>HTML file upload</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form>
         <input type="file" name="files1[]" accept=".pdf" multiple data-max="2"><br/>
         <input type="file" name="files2[]" accept=".pdf" multiple data-max="3"><br/><br/>
         Upload multiple files, and click Submit.<br>
         <input type="submit" value = "submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very cooooooolllll that works !!!!!!
2 questions :
- adaptable to listen each input field without submit ?
- its possible to to change {inp.label} in message ?

Comment: about label i found !

Comment: Sorry to hear ... It works in the snippet here - in the form that the submit button gets disabled and a warning is shown below in the console. What does your console say?

Comment: its realy strange console say nothing no error ..... but submit isn't disable and form ask html5 require function in other field