# Limit the number of files uploaded in multiple-file-input-field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Is There a way to limit the maximum number of files that can be uploaded in a multiple-file-input-field? I don't mean the maximum number of files uploaded in one stack by choosing from the file-explorer, but added to the input field at all.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to limit it before it being added?

Comment: @PrikeshSavla Im not sure i understand the Question. I want to limit the absolute number of files uploaded, no matte rhow often the user chooses new files. so i guess the answer to your question would be yes

Comment: But you dont mind it the validation happens after the user has chosen the files right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854946/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-file-upload-in-html#15854971

Answer (score 0):

You can use the files attribute of the file input to determine how many files are in it.

```
$('.fileinput').change(function(){
    if(this.files.length>10){
        alert('Too many files');
    }
     //U can set value = ''; if you dont want to allow submissions

});
// Prevent submission if limit is exceeded.
$('form').submit(function(){
    if(this.files.length>10){
       return false;}
});
```